# Is there a way to only show selected property in a json object based on a array

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following object

```
calendarLists = [
    {Title: titel1, Color:blue, number:1}
    {Title: titel2, Color:green, number:2}]
    {Title: titel3, Color:red, number:3}
]
```

It has alot more property but for simplicity sake ill just show 3 properties. I also have the follow array [Title,number]

Now basing from the array I only want to show object property based on my array. My results should be

```
results =[{Title: titel1, , number:1},{Title: titel2, , number:2},{Title: titel3, , number:3}]
```

Comment: So you're essentially wanting to filter `calendarLists` based on the values in some array?

Comment: First, there is no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a string format. Second, you aren't showing any JSON in this question. Third, you don't have 3 properties, you have 3 array items that contain objects that contain properties. Lastly, what have you tried?

Comment: You can do this in one line using object-destructuring if you set aside the array specifying the target properties: e.g. `calendarLists.map(({Title,number}) => ({ Title, number }))`.  Not submitting this as an answer as it doesn't meet the specified requirements (basing the results on the properties in the array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the wanted properties as objects, collect them to a single object and mapp all objects for a new array.

```js
var calendarLists = [
  { Title: 'titel1', Color: 'blue', number: 1 }, 
  { Title: 'titel2', Color: 'green', number: 2 }, 
  { Title: 'titel3', Color: 'red', number: 3 }
],
keys = ['Title', 'number'],
result = calendarLists.map(o => Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] }))));

console.log(result);
```

The same with a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var calendarLists = [
  { Title: 'titel1', Color: 'blue', number: 1 }, 
  { Title: 'titel2', Color: 'green', number: 2 }, 
  { Title: 'titel3', Color: 'red', number: 3 }
],
   result = calendarLists.map(({ Title, number }) => ({ Title, number }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Both looks promising. What do you think between the two is more efficient?

Comment: the first one is for dynamic properties, the second if the properties do not change.

Comment: Hmm I have a dynamic array. ill go with the 1st solution then

Answer (score -1):

Your calendarLists has syntax error. You can map this array and filter wanted properties.

```
calendarLists = [{
    Title: 'titel1',
    Color: 'blue',
    number: 1
  },
  {
    Title: 'titel2',
    Color: 'green',
    number: 2
  },
  {
    Title: 'titel3',
    Color: 'red',
    number: 3
  }
];

result = calendarLists.map(
  calendarList => {
    return {
      Title: calendarList.Title,
      number: calendarList.number
    }
  }
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This solution is not dynamic at all